# Replace a number incrementally in same line using Perl

Tags: perl

I have some XML data like this

```
<!--Q1: some text--><!--Q1: some text--><!--Q1: some text-->
```

I want to replace this query number in order like so

```
<!--Q1: some text--><!--Q2: some text--><!--Q3: some text-->..
```

I wrote this Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$b=1;
use strict;
open(FILE, "<text.xml") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
my @newlines;
while<> { 
    $_ =~ s/<!--Q[0-9]{1,2}/<!--Q$b/g;
    $b++;
    push(@newlines,$_);
}
open(FILE, ">text.xml") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
```

but it only makes one replacement in each line.

My text:

```
<!--Q2: text-->
<!--Q3: text--><!--Q8: text-->
<!--Q10: text-->
```

output

```
<!--Q1: text-->
<!--Q**2**: text--><!--Q**2**: text-->
<!--Q3: text-->
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your program

- You must always `use strict` and `use warnings` as the first lines of your program
- You should use lexical file handles (scalar variables) instead of global names
- You should use the three-parameter form of `open`, and include the built-in variable `$!` in the `die` string if `open` fails
- You should *never* use `$a` or `$b` as variable names. They don't help to document the program at all, and they are used internally by perl so you can't rely on their contents
- You have read *the entirety* of the file into `@lines`, and then expect there to be more to read in your `while` loop. You have already reached end of file, so the loop is never entered
- It is pointless to test for *exactly* one or two digits following `<!--Q`. If there is an occurrenece of three or more digits then the regex will still match, but only the first two digits will be replaced
- There is no reasons to `push` the modified lines to an array and `print` them all later. Just print each one as you change it

Use this instead. Version 10.0 of Perl 5 is required for the `\K` construct in the regex. It has been around since 2007, so if you are behind with your updates then you should really get that fixed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

open my $in,  '<', 'text.xml'    or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'newtext.xml' or die $!;

my $n = 0;

while (<$in>) {
  s/<!--Q\K\d+/++$n/ge;
  print $out $_;
}
```

**output**

```
<!--Q1: text-->
<!--Q2: text--><!--Q3: text-->
<!--Q4: text-->
```

---

**Update**

If you don't have version 10 of Perl 5 available (and you really should - it is *six years* old and a major update) then you can write the regular expression like this

```
s/(<!--Q)\d+/$1.++$n/ge;
```

Comment: @Kenosis: Bizarre: I thought that was a straight copy/paste of a working program. I guess I tinkered with it after the last run. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You're most welcome.  Only returning just a little of the help you've given me.

Comment: How to run this script for all *.xml file in folder?